# Xcode Error: "/R.swift/rswift: No such file or directory"

Tags: swift

Receiving this error:

`/Users/brendanwinter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sidearm-bpmbvflilopwujbzzhkazqidiguc/Build/Intermediates/Sidearm.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/louisville.build/Script-52247AC61D89704E005DF2FA.sh: line 2: /R.swift/rswift: No such file or directory`

[image: Screenshot 1]

I have tried:

- Reinstall Pods
- Updating CocoaPods
- Clearing DerivedData folder
- Clean Build

Comment: The link to the image you've posted does not point to a valid image. Try to remove the file and then re-add it. Also add it in build resources.

Comment: It looks to me like there is an error in whatever that run script is. It's trying to access some file but it looks like it's listing a swift file as a folder? I'm not sure but `/R.swift/rswift` seems confusing and almost backwards to me, like it should be something like `/rswift/R.swift` which would be a file called `R.swift` in the folder `rswift` - but that's purely conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift) code generator (which I'm a collaborator on).

If you're installing it using Cocoapods ([installation instructions](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift#cocoapods-recommended)), make sure you point to the correct directory in your run script:

```
"$PODS_ROOT/R.swift/rswift" generate "$SRCROOT/R.generated.swift"
```

Note the `$PODS_ROOT` here, that usually points to the `Pods` directory at the root of your project.
If you exclude that from the run script, Xcode won't be able to find the `rswift` executable.

Comment: For newer version of R.swift, you need `"$PODS_ROOT/R.swift/rswift" generate "$SRCROOT/R.generated.swift"`

Answer (score 2):

check in Podfile. move

`pod 'R.swift'  # https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift`

from target 'you project ...Tests' do

to

`target 'You project' do`

I get crazy bug, so I check pod file again and it go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
  target 'You project' do
     pod 'R.swift'

     target 'Other target' # Prevent compile error (add this block resolve my compile error)
  end
```

Comment: You may want to add explanation for the code.

Comment: Just add- "update your Podfile as so.." and that will help add some context to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also delete your pod folder and re-install pods with

> pod install